# how to handle corrupted terraform tfstate file

Tags: terraform

I am running an application inside pod in aks, that is provisioning a aws service using terraform, if that pod is deleted or stopped in between when provisioning is going on, the terraform state file is corrupted.

When I try provisioning again using that state file I get apply error. Some of the resources got provisioned but are not updated in the state file. I get following error.

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_s3_bucket.examplebucket: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_s3_bucket.examplebucket: Error creating S3 bucket: BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou: Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it.
        status code: 409
```

so how to update the state file so I can use it again?

Comment: try terraform refresh -h

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the error is related to kubernetes resources and pods.

But if you need refresh / recreate the bucket, you can [taint](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/taint.html) it.

```
terraform taint aws_s3_bucket.examplebucket
terraform plan
terraform apply
```

Let me know if this is helpful or not.

Comment: Thanks I will check that.

Comment: The resource aws_s3_bucket.examplebucket couldn't be found in the module root. I am getting this error from terraform

Answer (score 0):

If terraform tries to create something that already exists, you will need to **import** the resource into terraform.

Every kind of terraform resource, in this case a [aws_s3_bucket](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html), has listed in its documentation, at the bottom, on how to import it.

In this case, the following command should do the trick:

```
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.bucket **BUCKETNAME**
```

Replace **BUCKETNAME** with your bucket.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, it works but I have to import each and every resource which is  difficult in automation.

Comment: Thats indeed only the first time, if you start with TF on an existing environment

Comment: Can you explain more about the solution :)